# EC2 VPC without NAT?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nat, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to have an EC2 VPC with a public subnet and a private subnet, but without having to have a NAT box? The servers on the private network would not need to talk to the outside world, just to a load balancer on the public network (which also has a private address).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the servers in your private subnet really never need to talk to the outside world (they don't download software updates? Don't use public NTP servers?), then you don't need a NAT gateway for them. And the servers in your public subnet don't need a NAT box, they will route through an EC2 Internet gateway.

Comment: How, then, do I delete the NAT instance? Or if I can't delete it, is terminating it sufficient to not get charged for it?

Comment: Remove it from your routing tables and then terminate it.